# Compiler error using TDateTime EncodeTime function

Tags: c++builder

I am using C++Builder 10.3.2 Community Edition on Windows 10 Home Version 1903.

I tried to use Remy's code below to get the UTC date/time.

When compiling, bcc32c issues an error:

> no matching function for call to 'EncodeTime'.

The call to EncodeDate is valid.

I've used exactly the same code in C++Builder 5 on Vista and it works fine.

I've been trying to find a reference to this problem without success. Am I missing something?

```
TDateTime __fastcall NowUTC(void)
{
    SYSTEMTIME SystemTime;
    ::GetSystemTime(&SystemTime);
    return EncodeDate(SystemTime.wYear,SystemTime.wMonth,SystemTime.wDay) + EncodeTime(SystemTime.wHour,SystemTime.wMinute,SystemTime.wSecond);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the scope resolution operator, :: in front of GetSystemTime?

Comment: Removing the scope resolution operator does not make any difference.

Comment: Try parenthesis around everything after your return?  Sorry, just guessing here...

Comment: It doesn't help either. The error message "no matching function call..." seems to only relate to functions dealing with time. Functions related to date are OK.

Comment: I tried your code and i'm getting `[bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(3080): E2193 Too few parameters in call to '_fastcall EncodeTime(unsigned short,unsigned short,unsigned short,unsigned short).` Try the line of code i show in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EncodeTime needs milli-seconds added.  Try this line:

```
return EncodeDate(SystemTime.wYear,SystemTime.wMonth,SystemTime.wDay)+ EncodeTime(SystemTime.wHour,SystemTime.wMinute,SystemTime.wSecond,SystemTime.wMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Hi relayman. You are absolutely right. The millisecond parameter was missing. My fault. Thank you.

Comment: Note, the RTL also has an [`EncodeDateTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.EncodeDateTime) function that encodes both date and time in one operation: `return EncodeDateTime(SystemTime.wYear,SystemTime.wMonth,SystemTime.wDay, SystemTime.wHour,SystemTime.wMinute,SystemTime.wSecond,SystemTime.wMilliseconds);`. Even better, there is also a [`SystemTimeToDateTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.SystemTimeToDateTime) function to convert an entire Win32 `SYSTEMTIME` to a `TDateTime`: `return SystemTimeToDateTime(SystemTime);`